# Python Combobox: when I select an item(1), open a sqlite table in the treeview, and when I select the other item(2) open the same table

Tags: python, function, combobox, treeview

```
def connectmoon(*args):
            btn.config(state="active")
            Basedata = sqlite3.connect("src/compeletedlist.db")
            cur = Basedata.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE Mymoon (
                            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            NUMBERS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                            DATE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                            CODE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                            COLUMN_A INT NOT NULL,COLUMN_B INT NOT NULL, COLUMN_C INT NOT NULL, COLUMN_D INT NOT NULL
                                ) ''')
                messagebox.showinfo("CREATE", "Your Base Data was succesfully create")
            except:
                messagebox.showinfo(title="CONECT", message="Mymoons is connect")
               showme()

    def showme():
            Basedata = sqlite3.connect("src/compeletedlist.db")
            cur = Basedata.cursor()
            books = en1.get_children()
            for elements in books:
                 en1.delete(elements)
            
            try:
                Basedata = sqlite3.connect("src/compeletedlist.db")
                cur = Basedata.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Mymoon")
                for row in cur:
                    en1.insert("",0, text=row[1], values=(row[2]))
            except:
                pass
            
    def clean():
        
            try:
                messagebox.askyesno(title="Clean", message="doyo want to clean")
                if 1 == YES: 
                    books = en1.get_children()
                    for elements in books:
                        en1.delete(elements)
                        NUMBERS.set("")
                        DATES.set("")
                        CODES.set("")
                    else:
                        btn.config(state="disabled")
                        
            except:
                pass
 
    
    
    btn = Button(window, state="disabled" width=10, height=1, text="MOONS LIST", command = clean)
    btn.place(x=10, y=10)
    en1 = ttk.Treeview(fr2, xscrollcommand = ScrollbarH.set, 
                       yscrollcommand = ScrollbarV.set, columns=  ('#0','#1', '#2', '#3'))
    tuple = [("MOON")("SUN"),("EARTH"),("MERCURY")]
    list = Combobox(window, width=10, values=(tuple), state="readonly")
    list.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", connectmoon)
    list.place(x=5, y=30)
    list.set("-Select-")

    fr2 =LabelFrame(window, text="LIST")
    fr2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, ipadx=2, ipady=55)
    en1 = ttk.Treeview(fr2, xscrollcommand = ScrollbarH.set, 
                       yscrollcommand = ScrollbarV.set, columns=  ('#0','#1', '#2', '#3'))
    en1.column('#0', width=5)
    en1.column('#1', width=100, minwidth=100)
    en1.column('#2', width=100, minwidth=100)
    en1.column('#3', width=100, minwidth=100)
    en1.heading("#1", text="DIGITS", anchor="center")
    en1.heading("#2", text="DATES", anchor="center")
    en1.heading("#3", text="CODE", anchor="center")
    en1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
```

````
tuple = [("MOON")("SUN"),("EARTH"),("MERCURY")]
list = Combobox(window, width=10, values=(tuple), state="readonly")
list.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", connectmoon)```
````

when I select the first item from the combobox call the funtion but... WHEN!!! I select the second or the third item the same funtion is call```

my priority goal is take the info from the sqlite file when I select an item, load the sqlite Table (1), into the treeview
and when I select the second item from the combobox load the Table(2).

the first item connect to the first table from the sqlite
and when select the second item connect to the second table
so and on.
As result i can change the combobox item selected call?